Simple proof (avoiding Gamma function) for a Gaussian lower bound?
Let $g \sim N(0, I_n)$ be a standard multivariate Gaussian vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
It can be shown via use of Gamma function identities and inequalities that
$$
\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \leq \mathbb{E}\Big[\frac{\|g\|_2}{\sqrt{n}}\Big] \leq 1. 
$$
Question: Is there another way to establish this relationship without resorting to Gamma function calculations?
The upper bound can be easily established by use of Jensen's inequality. The lower bound, however, appears a bit more difficult to establish.

A weaker lower bound $\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}}$ can be derived from Gaussian Poincaré inequality.
